# Entity framework find row not in list

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

So I have two lists, one "students" and another "classrooms".

Each student is assigned a classroom, from the list of classrooms.

However sometimes a student is assigned a classroom that is not in the list of classrooms.

Is anyone able to tell me how to isolate the students with classrooms that are not in the classroom list?

I'm OK with querying all students and all classrooms and doing the rest from memory.

So far I have what's below. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
students.ForEach(O => classrooms.ForEach( **insert something here**)));
```

Comment: this asks for any basic linq tutorial, like ANY :)

Comment: How is a student assigned a classroom from a list of classrooms and then somehow in a classroom that doesn't exist? Are we dealing with two different data sources here? Missing FK constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
students.Where(student => !classrooms.Contains(student.Classroom));
```

might find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A guess at your relation between the two but this should show you the idea:

```
students.Where(student => 
    !classrooms.Select(x => x.ClassroomId).Contains(student.ClassroomId));
```